Class constructor with an expansible atribute
I have to make a system for a restaurant for a university project, but I don't know how to make the class constructor for the Orders class. Ineed a constructor that lets me add multiple meals from the menu, and only take the order ID and table after the user clicked on confirm for the meals.
I did 8 attributes for meals and meal quantity on my constructor:
public Pedido(int idPedido, int idPrato1, int quantPrato1, int idPrato2, int quantPrato2, int idPrato3, int quantPrato3, int idPrato4, int quantPrato4, int mesa){
        this.idPedido=idPedido;
    }

However this is not ideal, as I wouldn't know how to make the attributes of some meals null in case not all are used, and this has a limit on how much the user can order. What would be a good way to make this have as much meals as the user wants?

start creating a class/record to hold one Item of the meal (quantity and food), e.g.record ItemPedido(int prato, int quantidade) { }. Then you can write the constructor as public Pedido(int idPedido, int mesa, ItemPedido... itens) { ... }. Alternatives: use a List<ItemPedido> or even a Map<Integer, Integer> (key: prato, value: quantidade)

I did not understand this part of the syntax: "ItemPedido... itens". What exactly goes there?

oh now i realize that is actually just the writing, but a lot of errors popped up, i'm very bad at java so i don't know how to implement a record, list or map into the constructor nor how will i input this data later on when i'm running the program, i don't even fully understand what these are supposed to do. I think it would be nice to do a list, but i need it to be explained like i'm 5

English is not my first language, in Brazil we don't capitalize "eu", also, can't you let a typing mistake slide? I'm trying to solve an important problem for my project

I did not write anything about typing! Please be aware that just because two user-names start with user and end with 421, does not mean it is the same person :- )  Also better use the @user85421 notation in comments to address someone directly (not needed for author of post)

If you're certain this is a thing that you need, then you might choose to use a variadic constructor. Like,
public class Pedido {
    private int[] ids;
    public Pedido(int... ids) {
        this.ids = ids;
    }
    // ...
}


Builder pattern would be more appropriate.
